# Unable to install packages through npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Installing packages via npm shows the following message and nothing is installed..

`sakthiganesh@ubuntu:~$ npm install express

express@2.3.8 ./node_modules/express 

├── mime@1.2.2 ()

├── connect@1.4.1 ()

└── qs@0.1.0`

any solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express are installed already in your case. By default npm installs modules in the `node_modules` subdirectory of the current dir. If you want to install module globally use commands with `-g` key:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

But good practice are placing modules required for your application in the application directory. Go to directory, where your javascript file took place and run `npm install` without `-g`:

```
cd /var/www/my_app
npm install express
```